# aws configure command failing - ImportError undefined symbol: sqlite3_deserialize

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, bitbucket-pipelines

When running our bitbucket pipeline for all environments, the aws configure command is failing with the following error

```
+ aws configure set aws_access_key_id "${AWS_ACCESS_KEY}"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/aws", line 19, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 62, in <module>
    from awscli.autoprompt.core import AutoPromptDriver
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/autoprompt/core.py", line 16, in <module>
    from awscli.autoprompt.prompttoolkit import PromptToolkitPrompter
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/autoprompt/prompttoolkit.py", line 25, in <module>
    from awscli.autocomplete.local import model
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/autocomplete/local/model.py", line 20, in <module>
    from awscli.autocomplete import db
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/autocomplete/db.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_deserialize
```

We are unable to complete builds in all of our environments due to this AWS issue.

Is this a AWS CLI issue that we should report to AWS or something else?
[image: image of failing build in bitbucket pipelines]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing the bitbucket pipelines cached dependencies fixed the issue.

Maybe it was a slightly older version of the `aws-cli` that was failing and was being used?

Comment: It's hard to tell unless you share the relevant fragment of your bitbucket-pipelines.yml